# How to judge the covariance matrix?

Tags: matrices

As for a numeric matrix, how to judge that it is a covariance matrix?

For example, the following $3\times3$ symmetric positive matrix is not a covariance matrix.
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 4 & 8 \\
        4 & 2 & 7 \\
        8 & 7 & 12 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: A covariance matrix $C$ is always symmetric and positive semi-definite (i.e. all eigenvalues are >= 0). You can check if that is true. Or you can conclude that it is *not* a covariance matrix if you are able to find a vector $x$ such that the $x' C x <0$. Try $x = (1, -1, 0)$ for your matrix.

Comment: It is not a positive matrix.

Comment: @Innuo Thanks, that is just the condition I need.

Answer (score 1):

[Innuo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629044/how-to-judge-the-covariance-matrix#comment1325974_629044), Jan 6 at 14:01:

A covariance matrix $C$ is always symmetric and positive semi-definite (i.e. all eigenvalues are $\ge 0$). You can check if that is true. Or you can conclude that it is *not* a covariance matrix if you are able to find a vector $x$ such that the $x' C x < 0$. Try $x = (1, -1, 0)$ for your matrix.